# In Cartan decomposition, we have direct sum of vector spaces, no Lie algebras, right?

Tags: lie-algebras, direct-sum

I recently started learning about Lie algebras. I just noticed that being a direct sum of Lie algebras is not the same as being a direct sum of vector spaces.

Now If we consider a lie algebra $L$ with a Cartan subalgebra $H$, then there is a Cartan decomposition

\begin{equation}
L = H\oplus\bigoplus_{\alpha \in \Phi}L_{\alpha}
\end{equation}
So my question is pretty simple and it is just to be sure. Here we have a direct sum of vector spaces and not lie algebras right? for example  $[L_{\alpha},L_{-\alpha}]\subset H$ is different than zero in general, no?

Comment: Yes, indeed $[L_\alpha,L_{-\alpha}]$ is always nonzero.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation!

Comment: Note that general Lie algebras $L$ don't have the described decomposition, but e.g. semisimple ones over $\Bbb C$ do.

Comment: Are the L_{\alpha} ideals though?

Comment: No, as Lord Shark and yourself pointed out. Of course the whole point of the structure theory is that the decomposition is "a little more" than just one of vector spaces, namely, that one can compute how the summands operate on each other relatively easily; but in general, none of the summands is an ideal.